# How to repair a failed software RAID 1 (mirror) with Windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows-10, raid-1, mirroring

I have configured a Dynamic Volume mirror (RAID 1) using two separate drives for data only using Windows 10.

At some point, the RAID ran out of sync and never stopped resyncing, so I tried to find a way to fix this.

I have put one drive to "offline", but the diskmgmt.msc somehow crashed windows and turned unresponsive (after around 16 hours). I could not close the program or use the task-bar, so I hard-resetted it.

Unfortunately, the result was a failed RAID 1 "dynamic disk status: foreign" which I could fix using the "import foreign disks" option in diskmgmt.msc and after putting the second drive online it first looked like it was running as expected but I now have two different drives with different drive-letters and the same data on it.

I'd really like to have both drives use the same dynamic volume as a mirror like before.

Is there a way to do that without completely deleting the second drive?

Comment: If you have one drive that boots properly, then can’t you simply re-create the mirror using the other drive?

Comment: @JohnG yes i could but it would take very long (8TB).

Comment: You are mirroring 8TB? Can ask why you would "mirror" so much data?

Comment: @JohnG Why not? If it is all data and the promise of RAID 1 mirroring is having some level of redundancy, that makes sense. The problem is off-the-shelf drives nowadays are too big. But people still see dual disk RAID arrays as a decent backup option. And multi-bay enclosures more than 2 bays are pricier. Adds up to situations like this which stink, but make sense if you see what is available out there.

Comment: @johnG          the answer is easy: i got two server-drives from my boss along with some other "old hardware" (i might have paid for them idrc, if i did it wasnt much).
so nowdays games get bigger and bigger and installing them takes forever so having data redundancy is a nice thing to have. for RAID1, the READ speed is nearly doubled, wich greatly imprives loading times.

Comment: @dafriet - Sounds like you have a solution to your problem, a solution you don't feel is necessarily the best, but is indeed a solution.  You will have to rebuild the RAID.  There are other solutions that might exist, but all of them, require you have a backup of the data already.  Essentially, you would rebuild the array, but start from scratch and restore the data.  **Since you are using a software RAID you really are at the mercy of the software.**

Comment: @ramhound      yes, one solution. i will try to find a better one. i can't believe that windows has destroyed important parts of the data so there must be a way to merge the drives withouth completely rebuilding the raid, i have not changed ports or written data on either of both.

Comment: added as a comment because i am not entirely sure microsofts ToS does allow linking to it: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/foreign-disk/c8903760-aa6b-4b76-83dc-e11c10fcbad2